# JQuery determine if a link has been clicked

Tags: jquery

I am working on a private messaging system for my website.

In turn, when a user clicks a division it redirects them to a message.

In addition, when a user hovers over the division I display a link displaying "Delete."

The problem I am having is that if the user clicks the Delete link it redirects to the message.

I need to figure out a way to prevent the site from redirecting if the user clicks the link, but redirect if the div is clicked.

This is what I was thinking so far, but it doesn't work.

```
 $('.m').click(function(){
    if(!$('.mTools[id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').has(":focus")){
        window.location = '/messages/'+$(this).attr("id");
    }
});
```

Appreciate any help.

Update:

I'm trying this:

```
 $('.m').click(function(){
    if($('.mTools[id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').click()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        window.location = '/messages/'+$(this).attr("id");
    }
});
```

However, I get a "too much recursion" message in web console.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the click event and `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, not sure if this is the best approach or the JQuery way of doing this, but I figure out a solution.

```
 var toolsClicked = 0;
$('.mTools').click(function(){
    toolsClicked = $(this).attr('id');
});

 $('.m').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') != toolsClicked){
        window.location = '/messages/'+$(this).attr("id");
    }
    toolsClicked = 0;
});
```